# How can one publish watchos independent apps?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-6

I developed an **watchos 6 independent app**. How can I publish it? On **iTunes Connect** I have only ios and tvos apps available for creation. I could not find any information on apple website about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the process is quite similar with that of publishing an iOS app. With ios 13 apple piggybacks the existing infrastructure of ios apps to watchos apps. You can read more in [this article](https://medium.com/appssemble/building-an-apple-watch-independent-app-on-watchos-6-0-fef9a634ca77) I wrote, hope it helps.